# Como faço pra uma aplicação inserir dados no banco em tempo real?

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação que consome os dados de um servidor de rede, segue meu código:

```
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + asB64);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
```

Já criei o objeto com os dados e estou conseguindo gerenciá-los. O problema é que eu precisava que essa aplicação rodasse em tempo real pra poder salvar os dados assim que fossem consumidos no banco de dados.

Comment: Ou seja, você quer salvar o conteúdo lido no `br` no banco de dados? Se sim, em qual tabela? Qual banco de dados exatamente?

Comment: Ah, não use o construtor de `InputStreamReader` que não recebe o encoding, caso contrário você terá problemas de encoding. Use `InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`.

Comment: Você pode criar um serviço no seu servidor, que fica rodando de x em x segundos chamando o script que insere os dados no banco.

Comment: @Rodrigo Vaz Alguma ideia de onde posso conseguir algum exemplo?